# How to copy element from an iframe into main DOM in IE7 using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, iframe

I'm trying to move an html element from within an iframe with some event handlers attached (attached using jquery) to the main DOM of the page.

e.g.

```
var elem = $('iframe').contents().find('span');
elem.detach();
$(document.body).append(elem);
..
```

It seems to be fine in Chrome and FF, but in IE7 I get an "Invalid Argument" error being thrown.

If anyone knows some trick to do this that would be great.

Ta

Answer (score 1):

If the two elements are in different domains you will get cross domain errors.

read [this article](http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes) it might help solve your problems

Comment: The content is from the the same domain, and there's no problem in FF and Chrome - it seems to be an IE7 (although I've not tested it on IE8) specific problem